# JSTL only works when the field name in database is change

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
 <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="data">
   <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${data.catId}"/></td>
      <td><c:out value="${data.catName}"/></td>
      <td><c:out value="${data.parent}"/></td>
      <td>
        <form class="action" method="get" action="CategoryServlet">    
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="enable" />
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<c:out value="${data.catId}" /> >
          <input type="submit" value="EDIT" />
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="UserController" method="get">    
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<c:outvalue="${data.catId}"/>>
            <input class="disable" type="submit" value="DELETE" />
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

I am confuse here, jstl only pull the data when I change the name of field in database otherwise it throws the propertiesnotfound exception eg. I change "name" to catName and "id" to "catId" 
and use the jstl tag it works

but it doesn't work when I have fieldName: id, name

Comment: @BalusC can you provide me the link of similar question?

Comment: It's just in top of your question?